# Laravel 9, como puedo usar una condicion dentro de blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

quiero usar una condion dentro de blade para mostrar el estado de un usuario dentro de una tabla (activo o inactivo), para esto estoy trayendo los datos del modelo en el cual uso el numero 1 para marcarlo como activos y el 0 para inactivos

Este es el fragmento del codigo que estoy intentando usar, me podrian decirme que es lo que tengo mal?

```
 <td class="px-6 py-4">
      <div class="flex items-center">
          @if ({{$carrera->status}} == 1)
             <div class="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-green-500 mr-2"></div> Activo
          @else
             <div class="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-red-500 mr-2"></div> Inactivo
          @endif
      </div>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se encuentra en esta línea:

```
@if ({{$carrera->status}} == 1)
```

Las llaves `{{ }}` no son necesarias dentro de la condición `if`, ya que las llaves es en esencia como si estuvieses abriendo y cerrando etiquetas PHP `<?php ?>`, cuando usas algo de blade ya estas abriendo y cerrando etiquetas PHP por lo que no es necesario agregar las llaves para colocar variables de PHP

```
<td class="px-6 py-4">
      <div class="flex items-center">
          @if ($carrera->status==1)
             <div class="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-green-500 mr-2"></div> Activo
          @else
             <div class="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-red-500 mr-2"></div> Inactivo
          @endif
      </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación amigo, fue muy útil tu respuesta

Comment: De nada @Nogthings